# "Esconder" div por padrão

Tags: php, jquery

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site para acesso a vídeos sobre disciplinas, quero fazer com que ao selecionar uma disciplina aparecer os botões da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao lado deste select, fiz dois botões que devem aparecer após selecionar uma disciplina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realizei esta forma de "esconder" da seguinte maneira:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#disciplina_prof").change(function () {
      if($("#disciplina_prof").val() == ""){
        $('#seus_videos').hide();
      } else {
        $('#seus_videos').show();
      }
    });
  });
```

**Porem ao recarregar a página os botões ainda aparecem.**

Levando em consideração que "Selecione uma disciplina" tem valor "";

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row about-container">
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="page-header clearfix">
                <h2 class="pull-left">Selecione sua diciplina:</h2>
                <div class="box">
                <select name="disciplina_prof" id="disciplina_prof">
                  <option value="" selected=selected>Selecione uma disciplina</option>
                  <?php
                  if($num_logar > 0) {
                      do {
                      echo "<option value='".$fet_logar['disciplina_id']."'>".$fet_logar['disciplina_nome']."</option>";
                      }while($fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar));
                  }
                  ?>          
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
          <div id="seus_videos">
          <div class="page-header clearfix">
          <h2 class="pull-left">Seus vídeos:</h2> 
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Videos aprovados</button>
          <button type="button" id="video_pendente" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Videos pendentes</button>
          </div>
          </div>   
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, poderia postar parte do HTML?

Comment: Pronto @ThomasErichPimentel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui vc está escondendo os BTN dentro da função `$('#seus_videos').hide();`

Porém para esconde-los antes, basta vc colocar `display:none` no seletos que vc está usando `#seus_videos`

Com CSS ficaria **(indico essa opção)**

```
#seus_videos {
  display:none
}
```

Pelo jQuery basta vc adicionar essa lista fora da função

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#seus_videos').hide();
  $("#disciplina_prof").change(function () {
    .....ETC...
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar uma classe css que contenha o elemento `display: none;`
ou adicioná-lo direto na tag button, como abaixo:

## Edit

colocar o elemento `display: none;` em sua tag `div#seus_videos`

```html
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <div id="seus_videos" style="display: none;">
    <div class="page-header clearfix">
        <h2 class="pull-left">Seus vídeos:</h2> 
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Videos aprovados</button>
    <button type="button" id="video_pendente" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" >Videos pendentes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```